# Помогите найти ошибку в скрипте bash

Tags: bash

Помогите найти ошибку в этом скрипте. Вроде все по науке, но терминал на каждом условии пишет вот такое:
http://prntscr.com/hfg85k

[image]

```
    #!/bin/bash
    if [$#-ne]; then
    echo "Count arguments must be 2!"
    else
    if [$1-gt $2];
    then
    echo "first biggest!"
    elif [$1-lt $2];
    then
    echo "second biggest"
    else
    echo "=="
    fi
    fi
```

Comment: Вы забыли кучу пробелов

Comment: `[$#-ne]` — тут `[` — имя программы, а дальше четыре аргумента, которые от имени программы и друг от друга должны быть отделены минимум одним пробелом: `$#`, `-ne`, `какой-то-вами-пропущенный` и `]`. и дальше аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "Count arguments must be 2!"
else
if [ $1 -gt $2 ];
then
echo "first biggest!"
elif [ $1 -lt $2 ];
then
echo "second biggest"
else
echo "=="
fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

`if [ expr ]` это то же самое, что `test expr`, может так будет понятней:

```
if test $1 -gt $2; then
```